Does a snooker frame end when only the black is left?
In a snooker match, only the pink and the black are left on the table. Player A is 4 points ahead, they pot the pink making them 10 points ahead. Is this the end of the frame with Player A winning the frame?

Yes, if the striker wishes it.
Quoting from the official rules, in Section 2 "Definitions":


Frame

A frame of snooker comprises the period of play from the start (see Section 3 Rule 3(c)), each player playing in turn until the frame is completed by:
(a) an accepted concession by any player; or
(b) a claim by the striker, when Black is the only object ball remaining on the table, aggregate points are not relevant, and there is a difference of more than seven points between the scores in the striker’s
favour
[ some other ways not relevant here ]


The key point here being "a difference of more than seven points"
